# Accessing token used by Identity External Authentication in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I added a login with Microsoft account to my application based on [Microsoft Account external login setup with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

I generate my own JWT token that is used to authorize user while querying endpoints in my application, but I would like to ask Microsoft Graph "on behalf of the user" for some documents. I added proper Claims when registering the application in `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

Is it possible to access bearer token used by Identity to ask Graph or is there any other way if I would like to perform only one single login experience in my app?

One thing that worries me is that:

```
ExternalLoginInfo info = await this.signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

does contain 0 `AuthenticationTokens`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accessing the Access Token to have to set the property `SaveTokens` to true.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];
    microsoftOptions.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

This would add `access_token` and also `refresh_token` (if available) to Claims.